# Compare the value of 2 rows in 1 query

Tags: entity-framework

I have a table structure is like this:

```
USERID                 int
LOGIN_DATE             DateTime
LOGOUT_DATE            DateTime
LOGIN_STATUS           varchar(10)
```

The requirement is to retrieve the top 2 rows for a particular USERID sorted by LOGIN_DATE ASC. Then compare the 2 LOGIN_DATE records and check if they are less than 5 minutes.

Can this be done in a single LINQ statement?

Thanks
Parameswaran

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (untested)

```
bool isRecentLogIn = db.Users
                    .OrderBy(u => u.LOGIN_DATE)
                    .Take(2)
                    .All(u => u.LOGIN_DATE.AddMinutes(5) < DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me test and let you know.

Comment: @user3694237 Do you want to compare these two lines with DateTime.Now or the first derived line to the second one?

Comment: If Magos's second scenario is what you are after, you are going to have to build the collection and then make the comparison.